# If condition in C#

Tags: c#

I have this code that checks a cell in an Excel file.

```
var a = worksheet.Cells[i, 4].StringValue;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
{
    table.A = (DateTime?)GetResult(UploaddataBase.ProcessDateTime(a, i, null), "A").Value;

    if (table.A.Value < table.B.Value)
    {
        unexpectedExceptions.Add(i.ToString(), string.Format("A should be less than B for row number : {0}", (i + 1)));
    }
}
```

I want to check that if table.B.Value,regardless it exists or not in the file, to check this condition `if (table.A.Value < table.B.Value)`

This can be done like this?

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
```

or it is another whay?

Comment: Are exceptions not implicit unexpected ;) ?

Comment: I think this piece of code wont even compile. `var = a =` should be `var a =`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava it's a mistake.

Comment: @Aphelion that is a message. It's not really important,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `table.A` and `table.B` are of type `DateTime?`, you could do...

```
if(table.B.HasValue && table.A.HasValue && (table.A.Value < table.B.Value))
{
    unexpectedExceptions.Add(
        i.ToString(), 
        string.Format("A should be less than B for row number : {0}", (i + 1)));
}
```

Comment: you forgot a paranthesis at the end of the if statement